# expected ‘const char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘int’

Tags: c

I saw few threads about it but still no clue how to fix that error. The thing is:

```
    char *data;
    char chat;  
    snprintf(chat,"%d",getc(file));//error here
    printf("\Variable %c",chat); // here is still valid
    strncpy(data, chat, SHM_SIZE); //error here
```

Please help :)

sprintf - gives error (int to char conversion);
atoi/itoa - not working :/

Edit: @iharob
thank you! i still have a problem....

```
   strncpy(data, "a", SHM_SIZE); //is totally working
```

but

```
 char chat[SHM_SIZE];  
    snprintf(chat, sizeof chat, "%d",getc(file));
    printf("Variable %c\n", chat);//showing nothing or some weird signs
```

weird because

```
printf("Character : %c",getc(file)); //shows everything ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with the following

```
char *data;
char chat[SHM_SIZE];  

/* snprintf signature is snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...); */
/* read the manual please */
snprintf(chat, sizeof chat, "%d",g etc(file));
printf("Variable %s\n", chat); // here is still valid

length = strlen(chat);
/* you need to allocate space for the destination */
data = malloc(1 + length); /* 1+ for the terminating null byte which strlen does not count */
if (data != NULL) /* check that malloc succeeded. */
    strncpy(data, chat, length); //error here
```

please read the [snprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) manual

Comment: thank you! i still have a problem....
 

       strncpy(data, "a", SHM_SIZE); //is totally working

but 
   

     char chat[SHM_SIZE];  
        snprintf(chat, sizeof chat, "%d",getc(file));
        printf("Variable %c\n", chat);//showing nothing or some weird signs

weird because

    printf("Character : %c",getc(file)); //shows everything ok

Comment: It's because `%c` is the wrong specifier, i fixed the answer. I suggest you enable compiler warnings, it would save you a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

What is the first argument of snprintf ?
And what are you passing?

Are they the same?

What on earth do you think the snprintf function would do if the compiler allowed you to call the function?

The strncpy is just as bad. The first argument is an uninitialised pointer, so that is going to crash. The second argument is a char instead of a pointer, so that is going to crash. No idea what SHM_SIZE is but by now I fear for the worst.

This really looks like you are copying bits and pieces from various sources together without knowing what they are doing.

Comment: 1 - the first argument is char variable I thought will be copied do DATA variable. I wanted to pass specic characer from file to DATA variable using getc function.
2 - dont understand?
3 - i had an error, sorry, already fixed that. I wanted to store in DATA, chat variable